# How do I have a data entry form that adds the data to a column and checks for duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, is it possible to have a single field data entry form that adds the data entered at the end of a spreadsheet column and does not allow duplicate entries?

This is for an event entry system. Members have cards which have a barcoded number. We have a barcode reader that reads the card and appends a Return just as if the number had been typed in followed by the return key.

I want the spreadsheet to record the membership number in a column and produce a message/error if the number is already in the column to prevent two people using the same card on the same day.

This is to run on a Chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually done in two steps. the first is to collect data regardless of duplicates, and the second step is either to use an array formula to mark duplicates or query out whole collected dataset duplicate-less.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"ARRAYFORMULA HERE"; 
 IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(COUNTIF(B2:B,B2:B)>1, "Duplicate", "OK"), )})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(A1:D, "select A, B where D='OK'", 1)
```

[image: 0]